# Kubernetes Resource Declaration (GPU, CPU, ...)

Tags: kubernetes

How can I specify the CPU/GPU requirements for a Docker container in Kubernetes? I checked Kubernetes' JSONs and YAML (based on OpenAPI) but I cannot find any GPU declaration.

I expect that I could declare something like:
POD:
containers:
- name:
- resource:

and so on

Answer (score 1):

Requesting CPUs is straight forward:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: myimage:latest
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "1"
```

This means that 1 CPU core will be reserved for your container. If there is extra CPU time available, your container can use more than 1 CPU.

Requesting GPUs is similar, but requires plugins. Check the Kubernetes documentation regarding [scheduling GPUs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/).

> Kubernetes includes stable support for managing AMD and NVIDIA GPUs (graphical processing units) across different nodes in your cluster, using device plugins.

Comment: Thank you very much, what if I would like a pod to declare what is available?